# Nodejs loop through mysql Query give result = undefined

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

i have a Json Object and want to loop thorugh it. In my loop I want to execute a select query and save it result to another json Array.

So I start with a loop, performe a mysql query and want just log the results:

```
for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) {
     var query = connection.query('SELECT Id, date FROM tbl1 WHERE Id LIKE '+ mysql.escape(obj[x].ident) +'; SELECT Id, date FROM tbl WHERE Id LIKE '+ mysql.escape(obj[x].ident) +' ORDER BY date DESC Limit 1 offset 1', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {throw error;}
            if (!error) {
                console.log("resultset"+results); //<- Here I get the right result
                console.log("ID: "+results[0].Id); //<- UNDEFINED
                console.log("ID-LAST-entry: "+ results[1].Id); //<- UNDEFINED
                          } });
```

The Problem is that for booth results (0 and 1) i get = UNDEFINED.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you have an `Id` field within each result object in `results`?

Comment: @Pete: Yes, Id is in every result

Comment: Can you share the result of  `console.log("resultset"+results);`?

Comment: ok there we go. My resultset log = resultset:[object Object],[object Object]!

Comment: [object Object] is the result! Get nothing else.

Comment: Can you please try `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));`? I'm trying to get that object structure.

Comment: The Stringify result is = [[{"Id":"xx123","date":2017-05-24 19:59:21
}],[{"Id":"xx456","date":2017-05-24 19:59:21
}]]

Comment: So result /row = [{"Id":"xx123","date":2017-05-24 19:59:21}]

Answer (score 1):

From the value of `results`, You can see that it is **NOT** an `array of objects` instead it is an `array` of `arrays where each item is an object`.
You need to iterate inner array to get the `Id`. See the snippet below. Parsing the result into JSON and then reads the required data.

```
if (!error) {

    var parsedResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
    var outerArraySize = parsedResults.length;

    for (var outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < outerArraySize; ++outerIndex) {
        var innerArraySize = parsedResults[outerIndex].length;
        for (var innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < innerArraySize; ++innerIndex)
            console.log("ID: " + parsedResults[outerIndex][innerIndex].Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get -> ID: undefined

Comment: Isn't the `results` is of the form `[[{"Id":"xx123","date":2017-05-24 19:59:21 }],[{"Id":"xx456","date":2017-05-24 19:59:21 }]]` ?

Comment: the (stringify) result is : [{"Id":"xxx123","date":2017-05-24 19:59:21}]
[{"Id":"xxx124","date":2017-05-24 20:00:01}]
[{"Id":"xxx125","date":2017-05-24 20:00:03}]

Comment: Okay! That's different from one provided earlier. We don't have an outer `[]` there. right?

Comment: yes. The double [] result was an older Result, sry Dude my mistake

Comment: Lets try to log independent results. Can you try this? `for (var i in results) {
        console.log(results[i]);
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145740/discussion-between-pete-and-ckappo).